# Cannot read CD/DVD

Tags: dvd, cd, burning

Whenever I insert a CD/DVD in my drive, I cannot read them. Tried manually mounting them, but it shows: `no medium found on /dev/sr0`. I can only burn DVD (but not CD). My drive is okay, If I boot into Slax from my pendrive, I can read CD/DVD.

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal and run the following:

```
dmesg | grep -A8 CD-ROM
```

Insert a CD/DVD in your drive and try to read it.

If you still can't read the CD/DVD, look at the results of running the above-mentioned code. The first line of the results should show the name of your CD/DVD device. The second line of the results should contain the string sr0 in it, assuming that you normally mount CD/DVDs to /dev/sr0. The third line of the results should contain the name and version number of the CD/DVD driver that your system is using.

Now you can also run dmesg from Slax and find out if Slax is using a different CD/DVD driver than Ubuntu is using. I don't know if the same code will run on Slax, because of the string "-A8", but for this purpose you don't need the "-A8", but Slax does have the dmesg package, so instead you can just run the following:

```
dmesg | grep CD-ROM
```